# Change hyperref style in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  {
    \hypersetup{frenchlinks=false}
    \tableofcontents
  }

  \section{Section1}
  \label{sec1}

  \section{Section2}
  \label{sec2}
  \nameref{sec1}
\end{document}
```

I am able to change the style of links in the table of contents. However, in my actual document (which is too complex to paste here), the table of contents is rendered with `frenchlinks=true`. In `xelatex` output, I get the warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `frenchlinks' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 8.
```

I also use the option in my minimal example at `\usepackage`, and it works for `\tableofcontents` anyway. Why doesn't it work in my actual document? What causes this warning? How can I fix it?

**Edit:**

I figured out that it doesn't work anymore as soon as I actually load a font for the small caps:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Equity Text A}[
  SmallCapsFont={Equity Caps A}
]
```

Comment: The warning is there also for you minimal document. What is your precise question? Disabling the french link style in ToC?

Comment: Yes. In my minimal document, this works. But not in my actual document. Unfortunately I don't know what causes this and I thought it is possible to figure out the cause from the warning I get.

Comment: Do you load hyperref AFTER the fonts?  (It likes to go last.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, I load it after the fonts.